# Male and female astronaut fall in love on a mission and fall into the sun

Tags: story-identification, novel, space-exploration

I am looking for the title of a SF book about a male and female astronaut that are to go to the sun and back. They fall in love, missing the key moment to brake, which causes them to fall into the sun and die. It was written in the 70's or 80's.